# This is too much mess. How am I going to fix it? - is this a rhetorical question?

Tags: rhetorical-questions

**‎(1)**

> This is too much mess. How am I going to fix it?

**(2)**

> This is too dirty. How can I clean it?

Basically I am trying to say there is no way I can fix or clean it.

Are the rhetorical questions correct?

Comment: If you don't expect an answer, but you know for sure what the answer *would* be (and can reasonably assume your audience would agree on the *same* answer), it's a rhetorical question *(a question **asked in order to create a dramatic effect** or to make a point rather than to get an answer).*

Comment: IMHO, these could be confused for literal questions.  Perhaps try something different: e.g. "Oh, what am I going to do? There's so much mess/Everything is so dirty!"

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that "this" is in fact too much mess to be fixed, or too dirty to be cleaned, then yes, "How can I fix/clean it?" would be understood as a rhetorical question.

However, if "this" can actually be fixed/cleaned, or it's unclear whether that's the case, then, "How can I fix/clean it?" is ambiguous, and could either be a rhetorical question or a request for help. Tone of voice would play a big role if this were spoken.